# If Safari does not support the require attribute for inputs, how can I require a few specific inputs in my form?

Tags: php, html

If Safari does not support the require attribute for inputs, how can I require a few specific inputs in my form?  Currently, I am using this code in my PHP file triggered by the form to require all fields:

```
$req = '1';
```

that works effectively for requiring them all but I only want some of them to be required as opposed to all of them.  What are my options assuming I'm not going to use the "require" attribute?

Comment: I'm unclear on what your problem is. Safaris is a web browser, and it doesn't run PHP code at all.

Comment: whether the solution is PHP, HTML, or JS, I i don't mind, I just want to know how to require specific inputs on my website's form.  My current solution is using PHP.

Comment: You need to provide more code. `$req = '1';` does nothing at all by itself.

Comment: @Jay Blanchard:  That question that you linked looks like it has some really good solutions.  Thanks!